# Separate roles into modular parts that are interdependent

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a IRC bot that I'm writing (code is [here](https://github.com/jdloft/bot24-irc), bot24-irc.py is the main module).

This bot needs to be able to perform many different, separate roles so that each can be reloaded and sandboxed (for stability). I'm defining a role as being a function that reads all `PRIVMSG`s sent and returns a list of responses. At this moment, each role is in a separate module (just one right now, [phablookup.py](https://github.com/jdloft/bot24-irc/blob/master/phablookup.py)). I'm using the class `role` as a sort of wrapper to create a uniform way to "talk" to each module, to translate what the role modules want (a (different) function called with the right (different) arguments) to what the main module wants (a list of responses).

Here is the `role` class:

```
class role:
    run = False
    moduleName = ""
    checkFunc = ""
    args = []

    def init(self):
        if self.moduleName:
            try:
                print("Importing: " + self.moduleName)
                self.module = __import__(self.moduleName)
            except SyntaxError:
                print("Syntax error with " + self.moduleName + ", skipping...")
                self.run = False
                return 1
            except ImportError:
                print("Could not find " + self.moduleName + ", skipping...")
                self.run = False
                return 1
            else:
                self.funcToCall = getattr(self.module, self.checkFunc)
                return 0
        else:
            return 0

    def stop(self):
        self.run = False

    def start(self):
        self.run = True

    def check(self):
        if self.run:
            if self.moduleName:
                results = self.funcToCall(*self.args)
            else:
                results = self.checkFunc(*self.args)
            return results
        else:
            return ""

    def reload(self):
        if self.moduleName:
            try:
                reload(self.module)
            except SyntaxError:
                print("Syntax error with " + self.moduleName + ", skipping...")
                self.run = False
                return 1
            except ImportError:
                print("Could not find " + self.moduleName + ", skipping...")
                self.run = False
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return 0
```

And this is how I specify a new role:

```
phabLookup = role()
roles.append(phabLookup)
phabLookup.run = True
phabLookup.moduleName = 'phablookup'
phabLookup.checkFunc = 'lookup'
phabLookup.args = [msg, config['phabricator']['site'], config['phabricator']['apitoken']]
```

Now what I'm asking is this: is this type of module-per-role idea a good way to separate roles? Does it conform to best practices? It feels like its over complicating a really easy task. What is a better way to separate roles?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, when creating classes, you need to explicitly have them inherit from `object`, like this: `class MyClass(object):`. If you're using Python 3.x, then you can write them like this: `class MyClass:`

Secondly, the general style for naming in Python is `snake_case` for functions and variables, and `PascalCase` for classes. If you have a constant variable, then it should be in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

The following line of code in your `role.reload` function can simply be changed to `return 0`:

```
else:
    return 0
```

This also applies to your `role.check` function. `else: return ""` can be changed to `return ""`.

Also, I noticed that you're returning either `1` or `0` in your `role.reload` function. Do you mean to be returning `True` or `False`? This also applies to your `role.init` function as well.

Finally, in your `role.check` function, the below block of code can be changed to this: `return self.funcToCall(*self.args) if self.moduleName else self.checkFunc(*self.args)`.

```
if self.moduleName:
    results = self.funcToCall(*self.args)
else:
    results = self.checkFunc(*self.args)
return results
```

Comment: The point of this question was to get a second opinion on the use of modules to separate the roles of the bot, not just a general code review. Nonetheless, I have applied what you pointed out and have updated the question with the new code.

Comment: Or not since that's not allowed but you can still see at [the repository](https://github.com/jdloft/bot24-irc).